# WebClient Throws "No Data Available for Encoding 1252"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, encoding, webclient, windows-1252

Im making a program, which is working nicely, except i started to create an update system and somehow its not working. The splash screen checks for updates, using a webClient, which now seems to error as well. I set it up so the splash screen downloads a text file. If the versions mismatch, a separate form starts and uses a webClient to download the updater. I've created this form twice. It has 1 progressBar, 1 webClient, an image background and 1 label. The update is supposed to download, show its progress on the bar, and then open the updater and close the main program. The first time i created the form, i ran it and it would freeze and not download the file. After i stopped debugging, the design window of visual c# express 2010 would crash and I had to restart vc#. The window would show all of the items i had added except the webClient. So i tried debugging again and i got this message:

```
Error   1   Invalid Resx file. Type  in the data at line 138, position 5, cannot be loaded because it threw the following exception during construction: No data is available for encoding 1252.    C:\Users\DjLyriz\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TubeRip\TubeRip\updates.resx TubeRip

Error   2   TargetInvocationException: Type  in the data at line 138, position 5, cannot be loaded because it threw the following exception during construction: No data is available for encoding 1252.
at System.Resources.ResXResourceReader.ParseXml(XmlTextReader reader)
at System.Resources.ResXResourceReader.EnsureResData()
at System.Resources.ResXResourceReader.GetEnumerator()
at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.ReadResources(ReaderInfo readerInfo, IResourceReader reader, String fileName)
at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.ReadResources(String filename, Boolean shouldUseSourcePath)
at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.ProcessFile(String inFile, String outFileOrDir)
XmlException: Type  in the data at line 138, position 5, cannot be loaded because it threw the following exception during construction: No data is available for encoding 1252. Line 138, position 5.

NotSupportedException: No data is available for encoding 1252.
at System.Text.BaseCodePageEncoding.LoadCodePageTables()
at System.Text.BaseCodePageEncoding..ctor(Int32 codepage, Int32 dataCodePage)
at System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
C:\Users\DjLyriz\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TubeRip\TubeRip\updates.resx TubeRip
```

So i deleted the webClient from the form and retried. I got the same error a second time. So i googled the first error, and found one response on hackforums with no fixes. And now im entirely lost. All my webClients seem to be doing this now and i have no idea why.

Here's the code from my splash screen:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;

namespace TubeRip
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
        getupdates();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer2.Start();
    }

    private void timer2_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        label1.Text = "Loading Core Components..." + " " + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";

        if (progressBar1.Value < 20)
        {
            progressBar1.Value += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            timer3.Start();
        }
    }
    private void end()
    {
        timer7.Stop();
        mainpage home = new mainpage();
        home.Show();
        this.Dispose(false);
    }

    private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer2.Stop();
        label1.Text = "Loading Encryption Algorithyms..." + " " + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
        if (progressBar1.Value < 40)
        {
            progressBar1.Value += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            timer4.Start();
        }
    }

    private void timer4_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer3.Stop();
        label1.Text = "Enabling Download Services..." + " " + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
        if (progressBar1.Value < 60)
        {
            progressBar1.Value += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            timer5.Start();
        }

    }

    private void timer5_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer4.Stop();
        label1.Text = "Disabling Youtube's Download Protection..." + " " + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
        if (progressBar1.Value < 80)
        {
            progressBar1.Value += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            timer6.Start();
        }

    }

    private void timer6_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer5.Stop();
        label1.Text = "Drawing GUI" + " " + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
        if (progressBar1.Value < 90)
        {
            progressBar1.Value += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            timer7.Start();
        }
    }

    private void timer7_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer6.Stop();
        label1.Text = "Creating The first Humanlike Robot..." + " " + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
        if (progressBar1.Value < 100)
        {
            progressBar1.Value += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            end();
        }
    }
    private void getupdates()
    {
        try
        {
            string updateurl = "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22054429/TubeRip_version.txt";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(updateurl);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252"));
            string update = sr.ReadToEnd();
            int build = Convert.ToInt32(update);
            int thisbuild = 2;
            if (build > thisbuild)
            {
                label2.Visible = true;
                TubeRip.Properties.Settings.Default.UpdateAvail = true;
            }
            else
            {
                label2.Visible = false;
                TubeRip.Properties.Settings.Default.UpdateAvail = false;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to update server! Please try again later.");
        }
    }

}
}
```

And here's the code from my updater:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;

namespace TubeRip
{
public partial class updates : Form
{
    public updates()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void updates_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Uri update = new Uri("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22054429/TubeRip_Installer.exe");
        webClient1.DownloadFileAsync(update, "update.exe");
        webClient1.DownloadProgressChanged +=new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler( webClient1_DownloadProgressChanged);
        webClient1.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler( webClient1_DownloadFileCompleted);
    }
    void  webClient1_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("update.exe");
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    void  webClient1_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        label1.Text = "Downloading Updates Please Wait... " + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: No one could help with this one, so i did some research and decided to use UTF-8 encoding in a webclient instead, which does not throw this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find any result to my specific error, but i did find a way to work around it. Instead of using the default encoding for a webClient, i set the encoding myself to UTF-8, which does not throw this error. The modified code is what ended up working.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
Uri update = new Uri(uri);
client.DownloadFileAsync(update, "update.exe");
client.DownloadProgressChanged +=new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
```

Otherwise, i have found no fix to this issue, and no reason for this issue to appear.